# can I search for events based on time in neo4j?

Tags: ruby, neo4j, recurring-events, graphenedb

I am using the `neography` gem hosted by GrapheneDB.

I need to send out recurring events.

What I did with my previous DB is check if `object[:next_occurrence] is < TimeDate.now`

I don't see how I can do this type of search in neo4j nor in the documentation:

1. https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-sql-to-cypher/#_cypher_is_all_about_patterns
2. https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/wiki/Scripts-and-queries

Comment: check this out https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/08/20/graphaware-neo4j-timetree.html

Answer (score 0):

Using just Cypher, you can use the `timestamp()` function to generate a unix timestamp in ms (representing the current instant), which you can store as a property on nodes or relationships.

That can let you run these kinds of comparisons. So if you have nodes with `next_occurrence` properties, and you already have an `event` variable bound to a particular node, you could use a predicate like:

```
...
WHERE event.next_occurrence < timestamp()
...
```

With an index on the label/property, these kinds of predicates can use the index to find starting nodes fast (all events in the past, in the future, or within ranges).